# inherit a class without Initializing parent class django

Tags: python, django

i have a mqtt initializer class

```
class Initializer():
  def __init__(self):
     self.client = mqtt.Client(mqtt_server+str(int(time.time()))) 
     self.client.username_pw_set(
         username=mqtt_username, password=mqtt_password)
     self.client.on_connect = self.on_connect
     self.client.subscribe(
        "topic")
     self.client.connect(broker, mqtt_port)
     self.client.loop_start()
```

inherited this class to another class

```
    class publishdata(Initializer):
         def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.client.on_message = self.on_message
            self.client.on_subscribe = self.on_subscribe
        def on_subscribe(self, client, userdata, mid, granted_qos):
                print("Subscription started")
        def on_message(self, client, userdata, message):
            print("message.topic", message.payload)
        def begin(self,topic,data):
            self.client.publish(
                topic, str(data))
    publishData = PublishData()
    publishData.begin(topic,data)
```

publish and subscribe works properly. but when i call publishedData .client.connect and client.loop_start in the Initializer class  also runs.i dont want that to be excecuted on every publish call. is there any better way to do this

Comment: You have explicitly asked your subclass to initialise the parent class, that's what `super().__init__()` does.

Comment: is there any other way to do this with out initialization?

Comment: What do you mean by "i dont want that to be excecuted on every publish call."? More specifically, what do you mean by "publish call"?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to initialize a client every time that you create a new `PublishData` instance, then the code that does this initialization does not belong in the `PublishData` class. One possible solution is to create the client outside of the `PublishData` class and pass it in. This is called dependency injection. It looks something like this:

```
def start_client():
    client = mqtt.Client(mqtt_server+str(int(time.time()))) 
    client.username_pw_set(username=mqtt_username, password=mqtt_password)
    client.on_connect = self.on_connect
    client.subscribe("topic")
    client.connect(broker, mqtt_port)
    client.loop_start()
    return client


client = start_client()
publish_data = PublishData(client)
publishData.begin(topic,data)
```

Comment: got the solution . i have written  the initialization in settings.py  .client as a variable. then i have imported it. now it is working properly. thanks for your support